# Why is GroupBy in EF throwing "Nullabe object must have a value"

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

The query below is throwing the exception:

```
await RecipesComparatorContext.GlobalComparisonResults
             .GroupBy(globalResult => globalResult.IdGlobalComparisonResult)
               .Select(globalResult => globalResult.First()) 
               .Select(globalResult => new
               {
                   IdGlobalComparisonResult = 1
               })
               .ToListAsync();
```

However, this one works and i cann see the results with the debugger:

```
await RecipesComparatorContext.GlobalComparisonResults
             .GroupBy(globalResult => globalResult.IdGlobalComparisonResult)
               .Select(globalResult => globalResult.First())
               .ToListAsync();
```

The model looks like:

```
public class GlobalComparisonResult
{
    public GlobalComparisonResult()
    {
        Comparisons = new HashSet<Comparison>();
    }

    public int IdGlobalComparisonResult { get; set; }
    public int? IdItemRecipesComparisonResult { get; set; }
    public int NumberDifferences { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisteredOnUtc { get; set; }

    // Root subresult
    public virtual ItemRecipesComparisonResult IdItemRecipesComparisonResultNavigation { get; set; }
  
}
```

Comment: The two queries aren't equivalent. ` globalResult.First()` may not return anything in which case a `Select` after it would make no sense. What are you trying to do? That code seems to be doing the same as `RecipesComparatorContext.GlobalComparisonResults.Any()`

Comment: First() will throw an exception if there is no element.

Comment: Exactly Lady, i put the First() instead of FirstOrDefault() to see if ther was something null. Nothing is null, so the answer of Panagiotis shouldn't be the reason.

In trying to avoid duplicates (like with distinct), in real the assignment shouldn't be to "1" but to the id.
This is also a simplified example, and no idea why it fails.

Comment: The two queries aren't equivalent and don't make much sense. What are you trying to do? What do the actual classes look like? `This is also a simplified example` does it reproduce the same exception? If not, it's not a good example.

Comment: Please post enough code so people can reproduce the error. That means the DbContext, data classes, queries and sample data. LINQ isn't SQL and EF Core is an ORM, not a database connection. Their job is to load objects, not replace SQL, so they can't translate every possible LINQ query to SQL. Nor does it make sense to try to write a SQL query in LINQ - more often than not the results are bad

Comment: Panagiotis, the simplified example is generating the exception. I basically try to select from a table, group by a certain column, taking the first one, and create a new anonymous type. 
What I try to say with the working example, is that when I don't select into an anonymous type, then it's not throwing exception, and i think this may be a clue.

Comment: There's no `first one` in SQL without an explicit order. `GROUP BY` eliminates rows so there's no `first one` to return after grouping. That's why the code you posted is equivalent to  `GlobalComparisonResults.Any()`. What are you actually trying to do? Return one item per category? You wouldn't use `GROUP BY` for that in SQL either

Comment: Using property names that violate naming conventions doesn't help either, and makes this question very hard to understand. There are no `ItemRecipesComparisonResult` or `Comparisons` types in the question either, so one can only guess. `IdGlobalComparisonResult` is the key of `GlobalComparisonResult`, so call it `Id`. You're trying to group a table by its Id, which returns all ID values. Adding `TOP`/First to that would have no effect BUT you can't just use `TOP 1` with `GROUP BY ID`. All other columns have been eliminated. You need to specify aggregates for them, eg `MAX` or `MIN`.

Comment: For what I want to do I would use Distinct in SQL, however I read that Distinct is happening in the client side, and I want it to happen in the DB.
About the First(), you are right that there is no implicit order, but I don't care, I just want to take one from every group.
Take in mind that the second example is working with group and first

Comment: Read where and for which database? Not for EF Core 6, and not for SQL Server.

Comment: "Read where and for which database?" you mean that Distinct is happening in the DB?

Comment: Try to enable [EF Core logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging) and see what's the SQL executed on the database. Copy it and execute it yourself directly on the database, and see if the data returned from db seems correct.